# how to display thumbnail of image & clicking on that link it should open in window for view in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to create thumbnail of image when i upload an image & display in window(To expand that image), when i close that window then it should back again to that page.
how its possible?
Asp.net c#
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What libraries (eg, jQuery) are you using or prepared to use?

Comment: i dont have any idea what to use? Please tell me how to use?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by inegrating shadow box into asp.net. Please see below link:
http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Comment: how to integrate with asp.net